# Google Chrome Extension - URL Parameter Manipulation - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

***Google Chrome Extension, JavaScript Issue***

The aim is on button click the prefix '?wcmmode=edit' is appended to the end of the current url open. It's working to an extent, in that it appends the prefix, however in some cases '?wcmmode=disabled' already exists and therefore doesn't need to be added.

***Example***: Google.com/hello?wcmmode=edit. You can see it appends an additional '?wcmmode=edit' to the end of the url when it's not required.

[Example shown in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tx6fe.png)

***Here is my code:***

```
document.getElementById("wcm-mode-disabled").addEventListener("click", handler_one);

function handler_one() {
chrome.tabs.query({
currentWindow: true,
active: true,
}, ([tab]) => {
const url = new URL(tab.url);
chrome.tabs.update({
  url: url + '?wcmmode=disabled',
});
});
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ,check the url for occurrence of  ?
 . If found do not append else append. Can be done as follows
                var url = 'http://www.tyh.com?tab';

```
            var newurl = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('?')).split('-');
```

Use that newurl now . Instead of ? Put your custom string  '?wcmmode=edit'